# Test Class for Attachments to Files on Task

Tags: apex, files

I have written a basic trigger which converts all the attachments as files on the task object. I am having difficulties to achieve the test class and below it is.

My test class is compiling but not executing:

```
@isTest

public class attachToFilesTest {

    @isTest Static Void createAttachwithFiles(){

        //Create Task.
        Task t         = new Task();
        T.subject      = 'Creating Attachments';
        T.Description  = 'The Good, The Bad & The Ugly';
        t.Priority     = 'High';
        insert t;

        Attachment att = new Attachment();
        att.ParentId   = t.Id;
        Blob bodyBlob  = Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body');
        att.body       = bodyBlob;
        att.Name       = 'attachHarry';
        Insert att;

    }

}
```

**Trigger**

```
Trigger attachToFiles on Attachment (After insert){

    // A collection of ContentVersion objects
    List<ContentVersion> cvl = new List<ContentVersion>();
    List<FeedItem> fiList = new List<FeedItem>();

    //Loop in through all the attachment records.
    for(Attachment att : Trigger.new) 
    {   
        String Parent;
        Parent = att.ParentId;

            ContentVersion cvi= new ContentVersion();
            cvi.ContentLocation           = 'S';
            cvi.Origin                = 'H';
            cvi.PathOnClient          = '/' + att.Name;
            cvi.SharingPrivacy        = 'N';                       
            cvi.FirstPublishLocationId = att.ParentID;
            cvi.SharingOption         = 'A';
            cvi.OwnerId                   = att.OwnerID;
            cvi.Title                 = att.Name;
            cvi.VersionData           = att.Body;

            cvl.add(contentVersionItem);

    }
    Insert cvl;
    for(ContentVersion cvi:cvl)
    {
        FeedItem fi         = new FeedItem();
        fi.type             = 'ContentPost';
        fi.RelatedRecordId  = cvi.Id;
        fi.ParentId         = cvi.Original_Record_ID__c;
        fi.Title            = cvi.Title;
        fiList.add(fi);
    }

    Insert fiList;
}
```

Comment: Looks like it will run fine. What do you mean by "not executing"?

Comment: You will need to add logic that checks that your trigger has done what you expect; such logic often involves queries and then using `System.assert` methods to check the results.

Comment: Your test inserts only (doesn't update or delete). Does your trigger run on insert? Also before going much further I recommend you work through this [Apex Testing](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_testing) module if you haven't already.

Comment: Could you post your trigger please? It would help us immensely to know what action causes your trigger to execute. For example, does your trigger only fire on tasks created for Account or some specific WhatId? Where does the attachment come from? Perhaps you need to create the essence of the attachment first before inserting the Task?

Comment: Harry, please use the [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/225890/edit) link at the bottom of your post to update your question with your code. You can edit your post at any time you need to add information to it. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, please **[edit]** your post with any clarifications. Requesting additional details in the comments is fine, but providing such is not what they are for.

Comment: @crmprogdev - I am sorry and using stack exchange only for the first time. Thanks for correcting and updated the original post now.

Comment: Does your trigger actually work? I'd expect your trigger to be written to run on the Task and not on Attachment. Off-hand, I don't think Attachment is even "triggerable", but would have to run a schema describe call from workbench to check.

Comment: @crmprogdev. Yes indeed, it is working.

Answer (score 1):

As I read the details of your trigger implementation, it becomes rather obvious to me why you're not seeing any code coverage. Your trigger appears to convert attachments to content AfterInsert. I would recommend you convert this to a BeforeInsert trigger and here's why.

By running it AfterInsert, I'd expect the attachment to be created as an actual Attachment, not as Content. After that, your trigger executes, creates new ContentVersionItems, saves ContentVersion, then creates new FeedItems. From what I can see, it doesn't delete the original Attachments you inserted and it's not entirely clear to me whether it actually converts those attachments to Content or instead duplicates them.

As for your unit test, it needs to be run a query after the attachment is inserted on ContentVersion based on these criteria from your trigger:

```
 cvi.FirstPublishLocationId = att.ParentID;
 cvi.OwnerId                = att.OwnerID;
 cvi.Title                  = att.Name;
 cvi.VersionData            = att.Body;
```

to find the contentVersion, it's Id, and to Assert Results.

I'd also expect you to do the same when it comes to the FeedItem. You'll need to write a query and assert results using criteria along the lines of the following taken from your trigger:

```
    fi.type             = 'ContentPost';
    fi.RelatedRecordId  = cvi.Id;
    fi.ParentId         = cvi.Original_Record_ID__c;
    fi.Title            = cvi.Title;
```

Once you do that, you should discover you'll have the coverage you're looking for since you'll be able to relate the new content and feeditem records back to the original task and attachment records.

If you can't get results from your query, then the trigger isn't running in the context of the unit test. That can be issue with certain kinds of triggers which could make it difficult to obtain the coverage you need. Adding a debug statement or two to your trigger may be helpful in determining if that's happening to you with this trigger.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Trigger should remain as after insert and I am aware of the duplicate records which is by design. I will further work on the test class.